# Латинские и греческие окончания

Tags: этимология, заимствования, орфоэпия

Интересно, почему в русской транскрипции греческих и латинских слов всегда отбрасывается окончание "-ус" и ему подобные? Например, по-английски римское имя Марк произносят как *Маркус*, а у нас окончание отбрасывают.

Answer (score 5):

**"-us"**, написанное в конце латинского слова, означает мужской род. Как, например **"der"** перед немецким словом. Мы не пишем дер Штекер (der Stecker) , а просто штекер. Аналогично в латинских заимствованиях часто отбрасывали "us".

"-um" это средний род, "-a" женский род.

Например, слово "**лучший**". 
(Как это слово только не пишут на форумах :-D . "Лудшый", "лутший", "луччий"...)

*optimus* - лучший

*optima* - лучшая

*optimum* - лучшее

Пример из английского. Лат. *globus*, англ. *globe*. Но в русском, в данном случае, "ус" осталось. *Глобус*.

Answer (score 1):

Влияние современных романских языков. В них это окончание практически всегда отбрасывается. Зачастую даже в тех случаях, когда оно у нас сохраняется - например, мы называем пехотный меч римских легионеров "гладиус", а итальянцы говорят "гладио". С окончанием "-ум" то же самое. Мы называем парадный офицерский меч имперского периода "паразониум", итальянцы - "парадзонио".

С добавлением того, чего в латыни не было, кстати, та же история. Нерона итальянцы называют Нероне (а не Неро, как в латыни), Сципиона - Шипионе (а не Сципио) и так далее.

Почему это начало происходить у нас и в романских языках, но не произошло в английском и других германских? Скорее всего, дело в близости к латыни. Романским языкам латынь максимально близка лексически. Нам она лексически чуть дальше, однако чрезвычайно близка грамматически и фонетически. Потому и апроприация слов с переделыванием их на свой манер в обоих случаях происходит легче. В немецком языке тоже присутствует определённая грамматическая близость к латыни (он, как и русский, флективен), однако в нём есть совершенно чуждые латинскому языку артикли, а самому немецкому, с его громадным количеством согласных, чужда вокальная латинская фонетика. В английском же и вовсе нет ни родов (исключение - обозначающее мужчину и крупнейшие типы боевых кораблей местоимение "он", и обозначающее женщину и все остальные типы кораблей местоимение "она"), ни падежей (исключение - рудиментарные падежные формы личных местоимений). Потому германским языкам апроприировать латинские слова сложнее, в результате чего они трансформируются слабо, либо вообще не трансформируются.

Хотя есть и исключения. Например, когномен Помпея (который Гней Великий) англичане, как и мы с итальянцами, передают без латинского окончания "-ус". А когномен их с Цезарем соратника по Первому триумвирату Марка Красса - с окончанием. Вот тут чёткое объяснение найти действительно чрезвычайно сложно. Остаётся только почесать rapam, развести руками и сказать "так повелось".

Comment: В итальянском нет звука Ш. Даже для Сципиона. А на вопрос Вы так и не ответили.

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том, что в латинском языке, как и в русском, при склонении к основе слова прибавляется падежное окончание. И если к латинской основе прибавлять латинское окончание именительного падежа, а потом еще русское падежное окончание, то получится форменный винегрет. Поэтому обычно к латинской основе слова прибавляется русское падежное окончание, а латинское падежное окончание именительного падежа отбрасывается. В английском языке такой  проблемы нет, там слово не изменяется по падежам, поэтому они просто берут из латыни слово в именительном падеже, и этого им достаточно. А в русском языке такая проблема есть, и усугубляется она тем, что в латыни в именительном падеже основа слова может выступать в усеченном виде (например, Цицеро, при основе Цицерон и т.д). Поэтому мы говорим: Марк, Аполлон, а американцы говорят: Маркус, Аполло. И это еще цветочки... Так, греческое имя Аякс амеры произносят как Эйджекс, а наши филологи учат, что правильно говорить Эант...

Comment: В чем проблема-то, пардон? В литовском и латышском (к примеру) тот же случай, однако окончание -s именительного падежа в именах собственных не отбрасывается. И никого это не беспокоит.

Answer (score 0):

US - это окончание именительного падежа. 
Аналогичное есть в греческом -OS и некотрых других языках.
Сейчас подобные окончания обычно сохраняют при траслитерации (в прибалтийских, например, фамилиях), но ранее, когда латинский и греческий языки были более распространены и понятны, иметь чужеродное русскому окнчание считалось излишним. 
Зато часто приписывались "окончания", делающие имя более привычным для русского языка: Нерон, например, для латинского Nero. 
Иногда, впрочем, эти окончания сохранялись. Гелиос, например, для имени божества, но Гелий как имя собственное.

Answer (score 0):

IrinaGL,

Ну, видимо, вы не знаете итальянского. Классический советский учебник Добровольской, раздел "Правила чтения букв и буквенных сочетаний итальянского языка", 12-я страница, 2-й абзац (в ростовском переиздании 2005 года). Перед "e" и "i" сочетание "sc" читается как "ш" (если совсем точно - то как переходный звук между "ш" и "щ", но это - детали). Если хотите, чтобы у вас совсем уж сомнений не осталось - могу дать адрес страницы, на которой можно посмотреть отрывок из классического итальянского фильма 1971 года "Scipione detto anche l'Africano" ("Сципион по прозванью Африканский") и убедиться в том, как итальянцы произносят это имя.

А что до ответа на вопрос - то окончательные и неоспоримые ответы касаемо столь древней проблематики бывают редко. Однако приведённое мной объяснение является наиболее вероятным. Точно так же, как мы не можем безапелляционно судить о том, какой из современных языков наиболее близок к латыни фонетически, поскольку, по очевидным причинам, аудиозаписей того, как говорили древние римляне, нет и быть не может. Однако, если судить по тому осколку языка древних римлян, который зовется современной церковной латынью, то фонетически к ней, скорее всего, самым близким будет каталонский язык.

P. S. Заковыристая у вас тут, однако, система регистрации. Три попытки с двух имейлов, пока, наконец, подтверждение пришло.