# Ярош, Бартош, Лукаш, Тадеуш и другие

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Так почему у западных(и не только) славян и соседей "ш" на конце имен?
Это видел - [Латинские и греческие окончания](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).
И это - [Ярошь или Ярош?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/24540/%D0%AF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%AF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88).
Если возможно, первоисточник и автора. Спасибо.

Comment: Я не думаю, что ответ на вопрос "почему" здесь в принципе возможен.

Comment: Возможно, это заимствованіе у венгровъ. Въ ихъ именахъ распространено такое окончаніе.